# Rspec: controller example misbehaving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I am using Rails 6 with Ruby 2.5.5. I am trying to write an example for a controller method and something is baffling me for the past few hours:

Why does this:

```
post :create, params: { purchases: [{ board_id: 1, squares: [ [3,4] ] }] }, format: :json
```

pass these params:

```
POST { "purchases": [{"board_id"=>"16", "squares"=>[["3"], ["4"]] }] }
```

Note how [3,4] is being turned into [["3"], ["4"]]. It works fine in the browser, just not with rspec.

Comment: "It works fine in the browser" is pretty irrelevant when dealing with controller specs as they don't actually send HTTP requests and instead just pass the controller instance a stubbed request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/985 this fixed it:

```
post :create, params: { purchases: [{ board_id: 1, squares: [ [3,4] ] }] }, as: :json
```

Thank you Rspec!